# For all There exists For all

Tags: discrete-mathematics

are $\forall\exists\forall$ statements the same as $\forall\forall\exists$ statements?

They seem like the are the same, but I have never seen a theorem stating this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: Note that $\forall\exists\forall$ vs. $\forall\forall\exists$ is not explicit enough.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall x:\forall y:\exists z:z>x, y.$$

$$\forall x:\exists z:\forall y:z>x, y.$$

$$\forall x:\exists y:\forall z:z>x, y.$$

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not, just as $\exists \forall$ statements are not the same as $\forall \exists$.  Putting another quantifier in front does not change this.  If you have an example for two quantifiers, you can just add a variable and quantify over it to get the three quantifier case.

Comment: The problem is, I am trying to prove In Q, ∀x∃y$\forall$z((z>x)⇔(z≥x+y)). Can I prove this with y=1??

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Please help me prove this... I am so stuck

Comment: No, because it is not true.  We might as well take $x=0$ because all the rationals are the same.  Now what $y$ do you take?  Whatever it is, $z=\frac y2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: sorry, what $y$ would you take here? You gave a value for $z$

Comment: I gave a value for $z$ that depends on the $y$ selected.  If you claim a quantified statement is true, forall says I can try to disprove it with any value of the variable I want.  exists says you can find a value that works, so if I want to disprove it I have to show there is no value that works.  The choices go from outside in.  So for your statement I chose $x=0$ and asked you to choose $y$.

Comment: My claim is that no matter what $y$ you choose, I will choose $z=\frac y2$ and the statement is false.  I get to see your $y$ before I choose $z$, so this is fair.  If $y \gt 0$, $z \gt z$ is true and $z \ge x+y$ is false, so the whole statement is false.  You can try the other two cases for $y$ and they fail as well.